# Numerical Day Number of Year in InfoPath

Tags: infopath

I'm trying to get the numerical day of the year (so for February 3, 2016 I would get 34) in InfoPath.

I'm not having much luck googling this because I don't know what this date format is called.

Comment: There isn't a native function in InfoPath to get you the day number. I think you are going to have to derive it by doing a subtract of the current date from Jan 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am looking for is called a **Julian Day.** Here is what you use to format a Date field in InfoPath to return this value:

```
(((substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(now(), "-"), "-"), "T")) + floor((153 * ((substring-before(substring-after(now(), "-"), "-")) + 12 * (floor((14 - substring-before(substring-after(now(), "-"), "-")) / 12)) - 3) + 2) / 5) + (substring-before(now(), "-") + 4800 - (floor((14 - substring-before(substring-after(now(), "-"), "-")) / 12))) * 365 + floor((substring-before(now(), "-") + 4800 - (floor((14 - substring-before(substring-after(now(), "-"), "-")) / 12))) / 4) - floor((substring-before(now(), "-") + 4800 - (floor((14 - substring-before(substring-after(now(), "-"), "-")) / 12))) / 100) + floor((substring-before(now(), "-") + 4800 - (floor((14 - substring-before(substring-after(now(), "-"), "-")) / 12))) / 400) - 32045) - ((substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(concat(string(substring(today(), 1, 4)), "-01-01T00:00:00"), "-"), "-"), "T")) + floor((153 * ((substring-before(substring-after(concat(string(substring(today(), 1, 4)), "-01-01T00:00:00"), "-"), "-")) + 12 * (floor((14 - substring-before(substring-after(concat(string(substring(today(), 1, 4)), "-01-01T00:00:00"), "-"), "-")) / 12)) - 3) + 2) / 5) + (substring-before(concat(string(substring(today(), 1, 4)), "-01-01T00:00:00"), "-") + 4800 - (floor((14 - substring-before(substring-after(concat(string(substring(today(), 1, 4)), "-01-01T00:00:00"), "-"), "-")) / 12))) * 365 + floor((substring-before(concat(string(substring(today(), 1, 4)), "-01-01T00:00:00"), "-") + 4800 - (floor((14 - substring-before(substring-after(concat(string(substring(today(), 1, 4)), "-01-01T00:00:00"), "-"), "-")) / 12))) / 4) - floor((substring-before(concat(string(substring(today(), 1, 4)), "-01-01T00:00:00"), "-") + 4800 - (floor((14 - substring-before(substring-after(concat(string(substring(today(), 1, 4)), "-01-01T00:00:00"), "-"), "-")) / 12))) / 100) + floor((substring-before(concat(string(substring(today(), 1, 4)), "-01-01T00:00:00"), "-") + 4800 - (floor((14 - substring-before(substring-after(concat(string(substring(today(), 1, 4)), "-01-01T00:00:00"), "-"), "-")) / 12))) / 400) - 32045) + 1)
```

Formatted for better readability:

```
(((substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(now(), "-"), "-"), "T")) + 
 floor((153 * ((substring-before(substring-after(now(), "-"), "-")) + 12 * 
 (floor((14 - substring-before(substring-after(now(), "-"), "-")) / 12)) - 3) + 2) / 5) + 
 (substring-before(now(), "-") + 4800 - (floor((14 - substring-before(substring-after(now(), "-"), "-")) / 12))) * 365 + 
 floor((substring-before(now(), "-") + 4800 - (floor((14 - substring-before(substring-after(now(), "-"), "-")) / 12))) / 4) - 
 floor((substring-before(now(), "-") + 4800 - (floor((14 - substring-before(substring-after(now(), "-"), "-")) / 12))) / 100) + 
 floor((substring-before(now(), "-") + 4800 - (floor((14 - substring-before(substring-after(now(), "-"), "-")) / 12))) / 400) - 32045) - 
 ((substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(concat(string(substring(today(), 1, 4)), "-01-01T00:00:00"), "-"), "-"), "T")) + 
 floor((153 * ((substring-before(substring-after(concat(string(substring(today(), 1, 4)), "-01-01T00:00:00"), "-"), "-")) + 12 * 
 (floor((14 - substring-before(substring-after(concat(string(substring(today(), 1, 4)), "-01-01T00:00:00"), "-"), "-")) / 12)) - 3) + 2) / 5) + 
 (substring-before(concat(string(substring(today(), 1, 4)), "-01-01T00:00:00"), "-") + 4800 - 
 (floor((14 - substring-before(substring-after(concat(string(substring(today(), 1, 4)), "-01-01T00:00:00"), "-"), "-")) / 12))) * 365 + 
 floor((substring-before(concat(string(substring(today(), 1, 4)), "-01-01T00:00:00"), "-") + 4800 - 
 (floor((14 - substring-before(substring-after(concat(string(substring(today(), 1, 4)), "-01-01T00:00:00"), "-"), "-")) / 12))) / 4) - 
 floor((substring-before(concat(string(substring(today(), 1, 4)), "-01-01T00:00:00"), "-") + 4800 - 
 (floor((14 - substring-before(substring-after(concat(string(substring(today(), 1, 4)), "-01-01T00:00:00"), "-"), "-")) / 12))) / 100) + 
 floor((substring-before(concat(string(substring(today(), 1, 4)), "-01-01T00:00:00"), "-") + 4800 - 
 (floor((14 - substring-before(substring-after(concat(string(substring(today(), 1, 4)), "-01-01T00:00:00"), "-"), "-")) / 12))) / 400) - 32045) + 1
)
```